# C#: Appending *contents* of one text file to another text file

Tags: c#, file-io

There is probably no other way to do this, but is there a way to append the contents of one text file into another text file, while clearing the first after the move?

The only way I know is to just use a reader and writer, which seems inefficient for large files...

Thanks!

Comment: @Carn: Is that a hesitant answer? Or...

Comment: You can't "unlink" blocks of a file and "link" them to another file at the SO level (even because the point in the files you want could not be on the block boundary). You have to read, write and then clear. And if you want to do it transactionally... Well... Good luck! :-) This isn't SQL :-) (technically it's possible with newer Windows). If you only want to do it "normally", it's about 10/20 lines of code (perhaps less)

Comment: I cannot think of another way. I cannot improve upon Jon's answer, except to replace "file1.txt" with a constant (for best practice)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, I don't think there's anything which does this.

If the two files use the same encoding and you don't need to verify that they're valid, you can treat them as binary files, e.g.

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead("file1.txt"))
using (Stream output = new FileStream("file2.txt", FileMode.Append,
                                      FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    input.CopyTo(output); // Using .NET 4
}
File.Delete("file1.txt");
```

Note that if `file1.txt` contains a byte order mark, you should skip past this first to avoid having it in the middle of `file2.txt`.

If you're not using .NET 4 you can write your own equivalent of `Stream.CopyTo`... even with an extension method to make the hand-over seamless:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        }
        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because I wouldn't ever have thought of "cascading" the two using without adding another level of {}... Mmmh... Will the StyleCop flag it?

Comment: @Jon: OpenAppend doesn't seem to be a method of the File class, do you mean OpenWrite by chance? Also, CopyTo isn't available either, you are using System.IO for these... right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CODe: Whoops, was in the middle of checking that when the phone rang. Will fix. `Stream.CopyTo` is only in .NET 4 - which version are you using?

Comment: @Jon: Meh, 3.5 :(  I can switch it over for this small project though.

Comment: @CODe: That's fine... I'll add a helper method.

Comment: @xanatos I don't know if StyleCop will flag it (I wouldn't think so though) but I know Visual Studio won't try to "fix" the indentation if you have it reformat your code. (Specifically for `using` statements, it'll indent say nested `if` statements)

Comment: @Davy8 Checked. StyleCop doesn't flag it.

Comment: @JonSkeet in this example how do you skip past the BOM?

Comment: @Baz1nga: For that you'd want to read the file *as text* instead of as binary data. I suppose you *could* look for the specific binary data at the start instead, but it would be a pain.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you are certain your input file will have a certain BOM then is this a good solution for a Unicode BOM? `input.Position = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble().Length;`

Comment: @Baz1nga: Yes, if you're *absolutely sure* of both the encoding and the presence of the preamble, that's fine.

Answer (score 13):

Ignoring error handling, encodings, and efficiency for the moment, something like this would probably work (but I haven't tested it)

```
File.AppendAllText("path/to/destination/file", File.ReadAllText("path/to/source/file"));
```

Then you just have to delete or clear out the first file once this step is complete.

Comment: And hope someone doesn't have a full encyclopedia on a file :-)

Comment: I like this one-liner.  I'm sure someday, though, I'll be kicking myself and refactoring it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `cmd.exe` version of this is

> type fileone.txt >>filetwo.txt
>
> del fileone.txt

You could create a system shell to do this. It should be pretty effecient.

Comment: If you didn't want to delete fileone.txt but only "clear it" you could use `type nul > fileone.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "inefficient". Jon's answer is probably enough for most cases. 
However, if you are concerned about extremely large source files, `Memory-Mapped Files` could be your friend. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) for more info.