# using Stream CopyTo() without overwriting existing output file

Tags: c#, file, filestream

How do I use the [Stream CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) method without overwriting the existing output file?

```
public void MergeAndDeleteFiles(string outputFile, IEnumerable<string> inputFiles)
        {
            using (var output = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
            {
                foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
                {
                    using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }
             }
        }
```

The above method overwrites the outputFile for some reason? DO i need to set the position of the output file before using the CopyTo method?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096194/c-appending-contents-of-one-text-file-to-another-text-file

Comment: merging n files into an existing one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `OpenWrite` use `Open` and pass in `FileMode.Append`:

```
using (var output = File.Open(outputFile, FileMode.Append))
```

This will append the output to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append data, then use something like this:

```
using (var output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
```

Or

```
using (var output = File.Open(outputFile, FileMode.Append))
{
```

as suggested by Oded.

Comment: whats the difference? the first one opens it in write mode only?

Comment: @user917670 nothing. `File.Open` does, in the end, also call `return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);`.

Answer (score -1):

Use StreamWriter to write into text files:

```
// create a writer and open the file
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");

// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

// close the stream
tw.Close();
```