# C#Append data from one text file to another and then acknowledge user that it was done successfully

Tags: c#

I have a program in C# where I need to append all the data from the a text file to another text file, then the clear the first text file. Now I need some way to check if the data has been completely transferred and was successful and then display this information to the user in a MessageBox saying this was successful.

Here is what I am currently doing to append the data.

```
 private void updateLog()
    {
        #region ifexists

        if (!File.Exists(localLog + "A.txt"))
        {
            FileStream file = File.Create(localLog + "A.txt");
            file.Close();
        }
        if (!File.Exists(localLog + "B.txt"))
        {
            FileStream file = File.Create(localLog + "B.txt");
            file.Close();
        }

        #endregion

        try
        {
            //reading files into input & output
            using (Stream a_input = File.OpenRead(localLog + @"\A.txt"))
            using (Stream b_input = File.OpenRead(localLog + @"\B.txt"))

            using (Stream a_output = new FileStream(server + @"\A.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            using (Stream b_output = new FileStream(server + @"\B.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //copying from input to output
                a_input.CopyTo(a_output);
                b_input.CopyTo(b_output);
                copiedFlag = true; // I want some sort of flag to check, this is not much help
            }

            //clearing input
            if (copiedFlag == true) // based on that flag I want to clear the 1st text, if the data is not copied then I do not want to clear the 1st text file
            {
                File.WriteAllText(localLog + @"\A.txt", string.Empty);
                File.WriteAllText(localLog + @"\B.txt", string.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("synchronization");
            exceptionHandler();
        }
    }
```

All I'm doing is appending one file to another and then clearing the first file, but I want to make sure that the data is appended before I clear and loose it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're transferring file contents like this as opposed to simply [moving the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders#example-1)?

Comment: The only method I know

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems like overkill.  Why not use [System.IO.File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) method?  You don't need to open streams to do a plain file copy.

Comment: I'll look into that, as I said I am new to programming and I checked online this was one way I found. Thanks for help I'll look how I can simplify that.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But perhaps it's a homework assignment where he needs to do it this way? We cannot tell unless he indicates this.

Comment: One never knows!

Comment: @CiroKenzie You say you found this method online? Can you provide a link to what you found (so we know to avoid that resource)? :P

Comment: No, I work for a company where they had a programmer who did all this stuff. He left for a better opportunity so I am looking into for the time being and I sure am enjoying it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096194/c-appending-contents-of-one-text-file-to-another-text-file

lol here you go

Comment: for additional learning, you can also use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx), [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx), Or read the text and write text using [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), and [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @CiroKenzie Ah, leftovers from a predecessor... I've been in that situation before. And if [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) is any indication, this certainly won't be the last time we encounter this sort of thing.

Comment: @CiroKenzie BTW, that question you linked to is for if you want to *append* to a file. If you simply need to copy a file (i.e., not combining or otherwise manipulating its contents in any way), then that advice does not apply to your specific case.

Comment: I would still need an acknowledgement if I use System.IO.File.Copy, right?

Comment: @CiroKenzie Correct. But at least you don't have to deal with streams and whatnot first. Exactly how you do this acknowledgement is up to you and the particular application you're writing, but if this is a GUI app then I would give the [MessageBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) a look.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry then, yes I need to append. This program is for a test facility, where many testers test different hardware and the data is stored as a text file. This text file is then sent as a mail to the director of the company. So the text files from all users are combined into this one main text file and the mail is sent from this file. So I want to make sure that when data is being appended it was successful before I clear and loose the local data. Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton thank you, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @CiroKenzie Well, that revelation certainly changes things! Then in that case, yes, the question you linked to would be relevant in your case. It should provide you what you need, but if you have additional questions then please edit your post to include this new information.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton I'm so sorry, I just changed copy to append. Thank you for patience.