# How to append to the same csv file with ChoETL?

Tags: c#, choetl

Currently the code I have below calls JsonToCsv() to parse a JSON file and append to csv accordingly, so the result is as such:

result.csv

```
File Name    Page  Practice Name
file1.json   1     Associates & Co
```

However, as you can see i am using a for loop to iterate over a bunch of JSON files, and my intention is that it parses them and appends them to the csv. so the expected csv file should like like this if i have 3 json files:

```
File Name    Page  Practice Name
fileXYZ.json 1     XYZ & Co
fileAB2.json 1     ABC & Co
file1.json   1     Associates & Co
```

however, whats happening is that the csv file is getting overwritten and I only see the results from the last file in the csv file. How do i make it append to the same file?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Output to CSV
    foreach (var jsonFile in Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilesPath))
    {
        JsonToCsv(jsonFile, csvFilePath);
    }
}

public static void JsonToCsv(string jsonInputFile, string csvFile)
{
    using (var p = new ChoJSONReader(jsonInputFile).WithJSONPath("$..readResults"))
    {
        using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csvFile)//.WithFirstLineHeader())
            .WithField("FileName", fieldName: "File Name")
            .WithField("Page")
            .WithField("PracticeName", fieldName: "Practice Name")
            .WithFirstLineHeader()
            )
        {
            // Limit the result to page 1 since the fields below only exist on the 1st page
            w.Write(p
                .Where(r1 => r1.page == 1)
                .Select(r1 =>
                {
                    var lines = (dynamic[])r1.lines;
                    return new
                    {
                        FileName = inputFile,
                        Page = r1.page,
                        PracticeName = lines[6].text,
                    };
                }
        ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Appending \*contents\* of one text file to another text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096194/c-appending-contents-of-one-text-file-to-another-text-file)

Comment: @DCCoder no that's different. His is more complicated scenario and a different use case. Also hes not using a function in a loop. Lastly I did consider AppendAllText. However, that is applicable to IO stream, but I am using choetl which idk what the equivalent for that is, if even that is the solution...

Comment: So AppendAllText and using a FileStream append won't suit your needs? (Both of which are covered in the answers in that question).   Can you explain why you are unable to use either of these methods?

Comment: @DCCoder oh i see now how that can be done with Yegor's answer. `FileMode.Append` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st option. I'd recommend you to alter your method signature to accept multiple files.

```
public static void JsonToCsv(IEnumerable<string> jsonInputFiles, string csvFile)
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csvFile)
        .WithField("FileName", fieldName: "File Name")
        .WithField("Page")
        .WithField("PracticeName", fieldName: "Practice Name")
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
    {
        foreach (var jsonInputFile in jsonInputFiles)
        {
            using (var p = new ChoJSONReader(jsonInputFile).WithJSONPath("$..readResults"))
            {
                w.Write(p
                    .Where(r1 => r1.page == 1)
                    .Select(r1 =>
                    {
                        var lines = (dynamic[])r1.lines;
                        return new
                        {
                            FileName = inputFile,
                            Page = r1.page,
                            PracticeName = lines[6].text,
                        };
                    }
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd option. Use FileStream with Append option, and do some extra code to handle different cases, see comments.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\file.csv", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var writer = new ChoCSVWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.WithField("FileName", fieldName: "File Name")
            .WithField("Page")
            .WithField("PracticeName", fieldName: "Practice Name");

        if (fs.Position == 0) // we don't need header if file already existed before
        {
            writer.WithFirstLineHeader();
        }

        writer.Write(new
        {
            FileName = "Test",
            Page = 1,
            PracticeName = "Abc"
        });

    }

    fs.Write(Environment.NewLine); // append new line carrier so we don't write to the same line when file reopened for writing
}
```

3rd option - from comments (based on 2nd). Switch between create and append options

```
bool someCondition = true;
FileMode fileMode = someCondition ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create;
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\file.csv", fileMode, FileAccess.Write))
```

Comment: Interesting! So one thing I realized is that chocsvwriter nicely creates the csv file automatically if it doesn't exist. However, what if I want to append, like your options allow, but whenever a new session is initiated it creates (overwrites) existing file (if any)? That would be a nice 3rd option

Comment: just pass a boolean flag that will flip FileMode.Append to FileMode.Create

Comment: I edited my answer, please check. `someCondition` can be passed through parameters

Comment: i just tried out the 2nd option and it works amazing! however, i had to get rid of the `?` from `writer?.Dispose();` in the finally block because otherwise it was appending very strangely.

Comment: it is confusing, `?` is just a null check. I don't think it can affect csv writing

Comment: very strange, what was happening is it was appending the same file twice. however, when i got rid of it, it appended the other file information as i had expected. is it maybe cause i wrappend the 2nd option around another using, `using (var p = new ChoJSONReader(jsonInputFile).WithJSONPath("$..readResults")) // "readResults": [
                    {` so i can get the advantage of my old code                              `writer.Write(p
                                    .Where(r1 => r1.page == 1)
                                    .Select(r1 =>....`

Comment: also i think the 3rd option is partially what i am looking for for creating a new file. However, what is currently the case is that i have to manually switch the boolean condition. what i meant was, i want the `bool someCondition = true;` to be set whenever a new session (e.g. everytime i click run program) occurs; ive done some research on that however all i am getting is cookie and HTTP sessions examples. i guess i dont know what it is referred to everytime we click "run", and a new console window pops up, isnt it session?

Comment: yeah I missed it, calling Dispose twice writes records twice, so we need to track it too. I updated my answer.
*new session (e.g. everytime i click run program)* this depends on your application type and how you can detect new sessions. you might want to post different question for that

Comment: ok sounds good! although this is not critical now, i am thinking longterm if we have this job scheduled, it wouldnt make sense to append the same information every 10 minutes for example. or maybe instead of ceating a new file, somehow check if the information is already there (e.g. row already exists, so either overwrite it or dont append?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224454/discussion-between-yegor-androsov-and-cataster).

Comment: with `writer = null;` i was able to use `writer?.Dispose();`